# How to highlight multiple blank lines in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: windows-10, sublime-text-3

I use the latest build of Sublime Text 3 daily.

Let's say that I've a lot of files with blank lines in them.

```
Message 1

Message 2

Message 3
```

And it goes on.. How can I quickly highlight them all? Clicking and selecting them one while holding the Ctrl key is just too slow and time consuming for me. And I can't highlight them via holding the Ctrl key and scrolling, because it'll highlight lines that aren't blank.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12008986

Answer (score 1):

With regex mode on, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, use the `^$` pattern, then click on "Find all". Regular expression might need fine tuning in case you have non visible chars on *blank* lines